# how can i set data to text view in the broadcast receiver's onreceive method

Tags: android

i want to use text view set text method in the broacast receiver class but it is not initializing text view object from the main activity.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView t1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}}
```

Broadcast receiver where i want to set data in textview which is received through broadcast intent. Toast is working fine

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    String action=intent.getAction();
    String data=intent.getExtras().getString("msg");
    Toast.makeText(context,"Detected: "+action +": "+data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make MyReceiver inner class of MainActivity, and there you can update your TextView. Register it in onStart, and unregister in onStop.

Comment: I think it's about not mentioning runOnUiThread - it is not needed, because onReceive will run on UI thread

Comment: how to register broadcast receiver dynamically ?

Comment: after implementing your solution. broadcast receiver is not wroking if my app is closed. if my app is open its working. i want broadcast receiver to be working even if app is closed

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code on the `UI thread` to do any kind of update to `view` from `receiver`! use this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText("Your Text");
                }
            });
```

Comment: yes you should put it there or anywhere that is not related to UI but you want to update the UI element.

Comment: cannot resolve method 'runOnUiThread(anonymus java.lang.Runnable)' see pic here - https://s29.postimg.org/yaz21z71z/Screenshot_224.png